# Nifi processor cron based scheduling

Tags: hadoop, cron, apache-nifi

Below is the syntax I have tried with 0 30 0 * * ? or 0 30 1 * * ?, which should run at 12:30 or 1:30 midnight respectively.

Also I have tired running the flow with cron in nifi for every 20 minutes duration, it worked perfectly.

But we want it to be run, daily once at particular time as mentioned above example (0 30 0 * * ? or 0 30 1 * * ?).

But it is not working. can anyone please guide.

Thanks.

Comment: [check cron syntax here](https://crontab.guru/#30_12_*_*_*)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have followed that, 12:30 midnight means it will 00:30 right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ahmed,

You have use below cron expression to run processor daily at 12:30PM

```
0 30 12 1/1 * ? *
```

Check it here:http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: Thank you so much. Will try with this. Really appreciate.

Comment: Ya for sure. I have updated the same into nifi as 0 30 0 1/1 * ? * to run daily at 12:30 am daily. So let me check whether it will work out at the particular time. Then will accept it for sure.

Comment: Ahmed,Please let me know if it is worked or not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just now I tried like for time 19:10 below:-

0 10 19 1/1 * ? *

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can make cron scheduling for NiFi using the link [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form:

```
0 30 1 * * ?
```

This is actually an example from Nifi documentation:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html

And here's a complete tutorial on cron:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html